# Elasticsearch timestamp range does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm writing a rule for alerting using Elasticsearch v7.16.2. There are mistakes in the query because it does not match with any documents, but it actually should. **I want the rule to ONLY be triggered during the day.**

I used a script to filter documents based on the hour they were created. For some reason the query never finds any documents, why is that? I believe the syntax is correct. **Do I need additional script to filter the day?**

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
              { "match": {"fields.Application": "WebHost"}},
              { "match": {"methodName": "GetClientData"}}
              ],
        "filter": [
            {
            "script": {
                "script": {
                  "source": "doc.date.date.getHourOfDay() >= params.min && doc.date.date.getHourOfDay() <= params.max",
                  "params": {
                    "min": 8,
                    "max": 17
                  }}}}
]
}}}
```

Mapping of my index :

```
{
  ".ds-prod_apps_template_v2-2022.10.06-000045" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "_data_stream_timestamp" : {
        "enabled" : true
      },
      "dynamic_templates" : [ ],
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "CardNo" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "Elapsed" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "properties" : {
            "Application" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "CardNo" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "copy_to" : [
                "CardNo"
              ]
            },
            "Elapsed" : {
              "type" : "double",
              "ignore_malformed" : true,
              "coerce" : true,
              "copy_to" : [
                "Elapsed"
              ]
            },
            "ElapsedMilliseconds" : {
              "type" : "double",
              "ignore_malformed" : true,
              "coerce" : true,
              "copy_to" : [
                "Elapsed"
              ]
            },
            "ElasticApmTraceId" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "copy_to" : [
                "trace.id"
              ]
            },
            "Exception" : {
              "properties" : {
                "Message" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "store" : true
                },
                "StackTrace" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "store" : true
                }
              }
            },
            "Identity" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "MachineName" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "OperationName" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "copy_to" : [
                "methodName"
              ]
            },
            "RequestPath" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "RouteData" : {
              "properties" : {
                "action" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "index" : false,
                  "copy_to" : [
                    "methodName"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "StatusCode" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "TraceId" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "Track2" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "UserName" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "cardNumber" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "copy_to" : [
                "CardNo"
              ]
            },
            "card_no" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "copy_to" : [
                "CardNo"
              ]
            },
            "loyaltyCard" : {
              "properties" : {
                "LoyaltyCardNo" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "index" : false,
                  "copy_to" : [
                    "CardNo"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "oldCardNumber" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "copy_to" : [
                "CardNo"
              ]
            },
            "old_card_no" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "copy_to" : [
                "CardNo"
              ]
            },
            "request" : {
              "type" : "flattened"
            },
            "response" : {
              "type" : "flattened"
            },
            "scheduler_record" : {
              "properties" : {
                "JobName" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "copy_to" : [
                    "methodName"
                  ]
                },
                "State" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "shopper" : {
              "properties" : {
                "CardNumber" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "index" : false,
                  "copy_to" : [
                    "CardNo"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "level" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "message" : {
          "type" : "wildcard"
        },
        "messageTemplate" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "methodName" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "trace" : {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
 
  ".ds-prod_apps_template_v2-2022.11.03-000050" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "_data_stream_timestamp" : {
        "enabled" : true
      },
      "dynamic_templates" : [ ],
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
        },
        "CardNo" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "Elapsed" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "properties" : {
            "Application" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "CardNo" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "copy_to" : [
                "CardNo"
              ]
            },
            "Elapsed" : {
              "type" : "double",
              "ignore_malformed" : true,
              "coerce" : true,
              "copy_to" : [
                "Elapsed"
              ]
            },
            "ElapsedMilliseconds" : {
              "type" : "double",
              "ignore_malformed" : true,
              "coerce" : true,
              "copy_to" : [
                "Elapsed"
              ]
            },
            "ElasticApmTraceId" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "copy_to" : [
                "trace.id"
              ]
            },
            "Exception" : {
              "properties" : {
                "Message" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "store" : true
                },
                "StackTrace" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "store" : true
                }
              }
            },
            "Identity" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "MachineName" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "OperationName" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "copy_to" : [
                "methodName"
              ]
            },
            "RequestPath" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "RouteData" : {
              "properties" : {
                "action" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "index" : false,
                  "copy_to" : [
                    "methodName"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "StatusCode" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "TraceId" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "Track2" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "UserName" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "cardNumber" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "copy_to" : [
                "CardNo"
              ]
            },
            "card_no" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "copy_to" : [
                "CardNo"
              ]
            },
            "loyaltyCard" : {
              "properties" : {
                "LoyaltyCardNo" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "index" : false,
                  "copy_to" : [
                    "CardNo"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "oldCardNumber" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "copy_to" : [
                "CardNo"
              ]
            },
            "old_card_no" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "copy_to" : [
                "CardNo"
              ]
            },
            "request" : {
              "type" : "flattened"
            },
            "response" : {
              "type" : "flattened"
            },
            "scheduler_record" : {
              "properties" : {
                "JobName" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "copy_to" : [
                    "methodName"
                  ]
                },
                "State" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "shopper" : {
              "properties" : {
                "CardNumber" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "index" : false,
                  "copy_to" : [
                    "CardNo"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "level" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "message" : {
          "type" : "wildcard"
        },
        "messageTemplate" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "methodName" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "trace" : {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Sample document:

```
{
  "_index": ".ds-prod_apps_template_v2-2022.11.03-000050",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "61UMYYQBEuG6snQ2U6L8",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2022-11-10T12:18:27.5940877+02:00",
    "level": "Information",
    "messageTemplate": "Executed {OperationName}",
    "message": "Executed \"GetPets\"",
    "fields": {
      "OperationName": "GetPets",
      "MachineName": "LTS-APPS122",
      "EnvironmentUserName": "MAXIMA\\SVC_LoyaCard_LT",
      "CardNo": "9440003700655430974",
      "response": [],
      "EndDateTime": "2022-11-10T12:18:27.5940877+02:00",
      "TraceId": "76f7374f-6fc6-459a-b997-d41bd95b9204",
      "request": {
        "SessionID": "8A6BA6C3DB624B1B96ED1A37F0197DE4"
      },
      "StartDateTime": "2022-11-10T12:18:27.5628410+02:00",
      "Application": "WebHost"
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "fields.TraceId": [
      "76f7374f-6fc6-459a-b997-d41bd95b9204"
    ],
    "fields.StartDateTime": [
      "2022-11-10T12:18:27.5628410+02:00"
    ],
    "level": [
      "Information"
    ],
    "fields.MachineName": [
      "LTS-APPS122"
    ],
    "methodName": [
      "GetPets"
    ],
    "message": [
      "Executed \"GetPets\""
    ],
    "fields.CardNo": [
      "9440003700655430974"
    ],
    "fields.OperationName": [
      "GetPets"
    ],
    "CardNo": [
      "9440003700655430974"
    ],
    "fields.EnvironmentUserName": [
      "MAXIMA\\SVC_LoyaCard_LT"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2022-11-10T10:18:27.594Z"
    ],
    "fields.EndDateTime": [
      "2022-11-10T12:18:27.5940877+02:00"
    ],
    "messageTemplate.keyword": [
      "Executed {OperationName}"
    ],
    "fields.Application": [
      "WebHost"
    ],
    "fields.request": [
      {
        "SessionID": "8A6BA6C3DB624B1B96ED1A37F0197DE4"
      }
    ],
    "messageTemplate": [
      "Executed {OperationName}"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: To help we need to be able to reproduce the issue, please provide an smaple document, the mapping. More details

Comment: @Paulo I updated the question and added sample doc with my mapping. Looking forward to your reply.